# why is there comma separator after a method of object?

Tags: javascript

i am trying to follow a tutorial class building a Game. where i found those mysterious commas. can anyone tell me why should i have to put comma after every methods in an object.

```
let GameManager = {
        setGameStart: function(classType) {
          this.resetPlayer(classType);
          this.setPreFight();
        },
        resetPlayer: function(classType) {
            switch (classType) {
              case "Warrior":
                player = new Player(classType, 200, 200, 100, 50);
                break;
                let getInterface = document.querySelector(".interface");
                getInterface.innerHTML = '<div><h3>' + classType + '</h3></div>';
            }, setPreFight: function() {
              let getHeader = document.querySelector(".header");
              getHeader.innerHTML = '<p>Task: Find and enemy!</P>'
            },
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `GameManager` is an object initializer & according to mdn

> an object initializer is a comma-delimited list of zero or more pairs
>   of property names and associated values of an object, enclosed in
>   curly braces

```js
let obj = {
  prop1: 'someProp',
  prop2: 'someProp2',
  func1: function() {
    console.log(`${this.prop1} ${this.prop2}`)
  }

}

obj.func1()
```

`GameManager` is similar to the object `obj` & you call its method by `GameManager.setGameStart` and so

Answer (score 1):

> where i found those mysterious commas. can anyone tell me why should i
>   have to put comma after every methods in an object.

[**Ref**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_object_initializers)

No this is not mysterious This is what syntax of object is

You need to seprate `key/value` pair by comma except the last `key/value` pair

Answer (score 1):

You are getting confused with creating an object and creating a function. Here, you are creating an object. So the rules of creating objects are to be followed. Each property:value pair must be separated with comma-delimiter. **Please note that you can assign function as value of a property as you are doing in the example**.

```
let GameManager = {
//**THIS IS A PROPERTY:VALUE PAIR** 
    setGameStart: function(classType) {
      this.resetPlayer(classType);
      this.setPreFight();
    },
//**THIS IS ALSO A PROPERTY:VALUE PAIR
someProperty: someValue,
```

When creating an independent function, you don't do that.

```
function printSomething(){
console.log("something");
}

function printSomethingElse(){
console.log("somethingElse");
}
```